# Celery worker takes tasks fairly

Tags: python, django

I'm working on celery worker. And I have some questions.

I use 4 celery workers with concurrency 3. They are working for same job. They are looking at same queue.
when I make task, I make 4 tasks at once. but each tasks takes different time.
It is like this:

```
task_list = [task1,task2,task3,task4]
# task1 : takes 10s
# task2 : takes 30s
# task3 : takes 50s
# task4 : takes 70s

for task in task_list:
    result = current_app.send_task("task_queue",(task),)
```

It is sent to same queue which workers are looking at.
when I creates multiple sets of tasks, I expected this:

```
Worker1: task1, task4,....
Worker2: task2, task3,...
Worker3: task3, task2,...
Worker4: task4, task1,...
```

So that each workers works fairly enough
But What I actually experiencing is:

```
Worker1: task1, task1, task1,....
Worker2: task2, task2, task2,...
Worker3: task3, task3, task3,...
Worker4: task4, task4, task4,...
```

Because of this situation, when some workers work hard, the other workers do nothing.
I tried to add priority to tasks, and use additional options for celery worker, but it didn't help.

here is command lines when i activate celery worker.

```
celery -A django-project worker -n worker01 -Q task_queue -l DEBUG -O fair --prefetch-multiplier 1 --concurrency=3
celery -A django-project worker -n worker02 -Q task_queue -l DEBUG -O fair --prefetch-multiplier 1 --concurrency=3
celery -A django-project worker -n worker03 -Q task_queue -l DEBUG -O fair --prefetch-multiplier 1 --concurrency=3
celery -A django-project worker -n worker04 -Q task_queue -l DEBUG -O fair --prefetch-multiplier 1 --concurrency=3
```

is there any situation like this or is there any solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, all I can do is just shuffle sequence of tasks to that same number of task can go different number of workers

```
import random

...
task_list = [task1,task2,task3,task4]

random.shuffle(task_list)

for task in task_list:
    result = current_app.send_task("task_queue",(task),)
```

I hope I can find another way to send tasks fairly to workers